# Ice Caves tour in October in Iceland

Tags: iceland, winter-sports

I am planning to go to Iceland in October and want to visit Ice caves. But almost all Ice cave tours begin in November.

Can someone please advise if it is possible to visit them on our own?

Comment: "Advisable" is purely a matter of opinion. What are you actually asking?

Comment: @David: Advisable in the sense feasible. I don't think it can be opinion here as is reflected in answer.

Comment: @Lokesh That's not what "advisable" means, so I've edited the question to ask if it's possible. ("Advisable" means "Is it a good idea?", which is definitely opinion.)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The ice cave season in Iceland is short, from mid-November to about the middle of March (and is adjustable according to conditions). Outside of that season, it can be dangerous to go into the caves because they can, and do, collapse.

You should never, repeat never, go on your own; always go with a guide. Walking on glaciers is dangerous and, unless you know them well, it’s extremely risky. Glaciers move and shift, there are weaknesses, crevasses.

Mind you, no one will stop you; there are no restrictions about entering the ice field or caves. But, outside of high winter, the glacier is too unstable and changeable;  it could be your very last adventure.